# Difference between single quotes and double quotes when passing command through ssh

Tags: ssh, bash

When I send a command to a remote server over ssh what is the difference between:

```
ssh user@123.456.789.012 'foo'
```

and

```
ssh user@123.456.789.012 "foo"
```

I am not passing any variables, and I am getting different results when running a command remotely.

Comment: In what way do the results differ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably no difference for that example but there certainly would be for this one:

```
ssh user@123.456.789.012 "echo $PATH"
```

The reason is that bash will evaluate and substitute variables inside double-quotes *on the local machine* but will do it *on the target machine* inside single quotes.

The same is true for subshells:

```
ssh user@123.456.789.012 "echo `hostname`"
ssh user@123.456.789.012 "echo $(hostname)"
```

However, it appears to not be true for functions:

```
$ foo () { echo "Foo"; }
$ foo
Foo
$ ssh user@123.456.789.012 "foo"
bash: foo: command not found
```

Globbing also does not happen within double quotes:

```
$ ssh user@123.456.789.012 "ls -l *"
$ ssh user@123.456.789.012 "ls -l numbered_files.?.gz"
```

Comment: I am not passing any variables, and I am getting different results when running a command remotely.

Comment: It may help if you include the exact command you *are* putting inside the quotes in your question.

Comment: @BassKozz: besides things with `$`, escapes (backslashes) are also treated differently between single- and double-quotes.  Are there any of those in your remote command?

Comment: @Ladadadada Please consider this edit suggestion: http://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/5925 I think it was too much for me to approve and should be been left as a comment, but may be accurate.

Comment: I tested these as I posted each one and I just tested the subshell ones again to make sure, using `GNU bash, version 3.2.48`.  Your results may differ if you use a different shell or possibly even a different version of bash.